# OneDrive REST API - Requested Range Error While Uploading Chunk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, httprequest, onedrive

I've been trying to upload files to my OneDrive via HTTP Requests following this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) without success. I have the following steps rounded up **(Authentication, folder creation for the file, create an upload session)** but when I try the last step, byte upload to the created session, I get this error in the second PUT request:

**Requested Range Not Satisfiable {"error":{"code":"invalidRange","message":"Optimistic concurrency failure during fragmented upload"}}**

This is my code:

```
//Get File Data
byte[] FileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

//Create Upload Session
OutlookEndpoint = $"{AppSettings.DriveSettings.OneDriveSettings.Endpoint}/me/drive/items/{FolderId}:/{Name}:/createuploadsession";
OutlookResponseMessage = await OutlookClient.PostAsync(OutlookEndpoint, new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
OutlookResponseContent = await OutlookResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (OutlookResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    OutlookUpload OutlookUpload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutlookUpload>(OutlookResponseContent);

    //Check the Created URL
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OutlookUpload.UploadUrl))
    {
        //Chunk Calculation
        int TotalSize = FileByteArray.Length;
        int AcumulativeSize = 0;
        int ChunkSize = 327680;
        int ChunkBuffer = ChunkSize;
        int ChunkNumber = TotalSize / ChunkSize;
        int ChunkLeftover = TotalSize - ChunkSize * ChunkNumber;
        int ChunkCounter = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (ChunkNumber == ChunkCounter)
            {
                ChunkSize = ChunkLeftover;
            }

            byte[] ChunkData = FileByteArray.Skip(ChunkBuffer * ChunkCounter).Take(ChunkSize).ToArray();

            AcumulativeSize += ChunkData.Length;

            //PUT Upload of Chunk
            string UploadEndpoint = OutlookUpload.UploadUrl;

            string BytesHeader = $"bytes {AcumulativeSize - ChunkSize}-{AcumulativeSize - 1}/{TotalSize}";

            OutlookClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            OutlookClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);
            OutlookClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", ChunkSize.ToString());
            OutlookClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Range", BytesHeader);

            OutlookResponseMessage = await OutlookClient.PutAsync(UploadEndpoint, new ByteArrayContent(ChunkData));
            OutlookResponseContent = await OutlookResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (OutlookResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(OutlookResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            if (ChunkNumber == ChunkCounter)
            {
                break;
            }

            ChunkCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I'm missing something. I only get a SUCCESS message in the first PUT request, the others always give me the error described above. Here's an image of the error with the headers I send. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qICGm.png)

I'd appreciate any help, thanks for reading this far.

**EDIT:**

Got it working after modifying the the header configuration for the request and changing the way chunks are created.

```
//Get File Data
byte[] FileByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);

//Create Upload Session
OutlookEndpoint = $"{AppSettings.DriveSettings.OneDriveSettings.Endpoint}/me/drive/items/{FolderId}:/{Name}:/createuploadsession";
OutlookResponseMessage = await OutlookClient.PostAsync(OutlookEndpoint, new StringContent("{}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
OutlookResponseContent = await OutlookResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

if (OutlookResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    OutlookUpload OutlookUpload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutlookUpload>(OutlookResponseContent);

    //Check the Created URL
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OutlookUpload.UploadUrl))
    {
        using MemoryStream FileStream = new MemoryStream(FileByteArray);
        
        //Chunk Calculation
        int ChunkSize = 320 * 1024;
        int ChunkRemaining = 0;
        byte[] ByteBuffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
        int BytesRead = 0;
        
        while ((BytesRead = FileStream.Read(ByteBuffer, 0, ByteBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            if (BytesRead < ChunkSize)
            {
                byte[] LastBuffer = new byte[BytesRead];

                Buffer.BlockCopy(ByteBuffer, 0, LastBuffer, 0, BytesRead);

                ByteBuffer = new byte[BytesRead];

                ByteBuffer = LastBuffer;
            }

            try
            {
                OutlookClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                string UploadEndpoint = OutlookUpload.UploadUrl;

                string BytesHeader = $"bytes {ChunkRemaining}-{ChunkRemaining + ByteBuffer.Length - 1}/{FileByteArray.Length}";

                HttpRequestMessage MicrosoftResponseMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    Content = new ByteArrayContent(ByteBuffer),
                    RequestUri = new Uri(UploadEndpoint),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Put,
                };

                MicrosoftResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", ByteBuffer.Length.ToString());

                MicrosoftResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", BytesHeader);

                OutlookResponseMessage = await OutlookClient.SendAsync(MicrosoftResponseMessage);
                
                OutlookResponseContent = await OutlookResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (OutlookResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
                
                    ChunkRemaining += ByteBuffer.Length;
                    
                    if (ChunkRemaining == FileByteArray.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(OutlookResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you got a failure above. Please note that on failures when the client sent a fragment the server had already received, the server will respond with HTTP 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable. You can [request upload status](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem-createuploadsession.md#resuming-an-in-progress-upload) to get a more detailed list of missing ranges. Try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, I will try changing the way I create the fragments, perhaps the Skip and Take that I use is not adequate. Will update soon, thansk @Dev.

Comment: You're welcome @Diego. Let me know if the [above](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem-createuploadsession.md#resuming-an-in-progress-upload) helps.

Comment: Thanks @Dev, I changed the way I build the fragments yet the error persists but I think I know what happens now. When I request the upload status of the session after sending the first fragment it gives me an "Upload session not found" error. The response of the first PUT request gives me an item object instead of the expected object with the "nextExpectedRanges" value. I believe it thinks I'm sending all of the data in one chunk and completes the session after the first PUT. I tried specifying the filesize in the session creation request but still no luck. Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: Nevermind, found it! Apparently the content-range and content-length were the problem. Changed the header configuration from the HttpClient to a HttpRequestMessage and it worked perfectly now. Thanks a lot @Dev, I will update the original post with the working code soon.

Comment: thanks for the detailed update. Glad that it helped. Just provide an update to this thread or mark it as answered (put in Your answer below) - so it can be useful to others in community as well :)

Comment: Let me go ahead and update it in the answer... so it can be useful to others @Diego. Consider upvoting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that on failures when the client sent a fragment the server had already received, the server will respond with HTTP 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable. You can [request upload status](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem-createuploadsession.md#resuming-an-in-progress-upload) to get a more detailed list of missing ranges. Apparently the content-range and content-length were the problem. You changed the header configuration from the HttpClient to a HttpRequestMessage and it worked perfectly now.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Apologies for the delay, It's been a busy week so I wasn't able to update the OP until now. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Understood @DiegoDelCastillo. Thanks!!